# Void function to print two different answers using same variable

Tags: c++, function, void

My homework last week was

> Write a program that will read in the number of liters of gasoline consumed and miles traveled by 2 cars, then output the number of miles per gallon of fuel consumed by each vehicle and compare the two for fuel efficiency.

Which I completed. This week the project is to modify the previous project and

> Add two void functions:
>
> one called userInstruction that tells the user what to do
>
> Another displayResult that displays the original information (number of liters and miles driven) and the result (miles per gallon).

It seems I have managed to get it mostly working. It compiles and runs at least. However, Car 1 seems to be displaying the liters of fuel used and miles driven from Car 2, despite it getting the correct miles per gallon. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I'm completely off the mark in what she wants which is why I can't figure it out?

Also, as a side question, is there any way to get the "Do the same with car 2" into the `userInstruction` void function?

```
const double LPG = 0.264179;

double mpg(double miles, double liters);
void userInstruction();
void displayResult(double mpg1, double mpg2, double liters, double miles);

int main()
{
    char keepGoing;
    double liters, miles, mpg1, mpg2;
    do
    {
        userInstruction();
        cin >> liters;
        cin >> miles;
        //calling function
        mpg1 = mpg(miles, liters);

        cout << endl << endl << "Do the same for Car 2. \n" << endl;
        cin >> liters;
        cin >> miles;

        mpg2 = mpg(miles, liters);

        displayResult(mpg1, mpg2, liters, miles);

        if (mpg1 == mpg2)
        {
            cout << "Both cars have the same fuel efficiency. \n" << endl;
        }
        else if (mpg1 > mpg2)
        {
            cout << "Car 1 has better fuel efficiency. \n" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Car 2 has better fuel efficency. \n" << endl;
        }
        //Allows for repeating
        cout << "Do you wish to keep going? (y/n)  \n";
        cin >> keepGoing;
    }

    while (keepGoing == 'y' || keepGoing == 'Y');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double mpg(double miles, double liters)
{
    double milesPerGallon;
    milesPerGallon = miles / (liters * LPG);
    return milesPerGallon;
}

void userInstruction()
{
    cout << "Please enter the liters of gasoline consumed as well as the miles travelled. \n" << endl;
}

void displayResult(double mpg1, double mpg2, double liters, double miles)
{
    cout << "Car 1 used: " << liters << " liters of fuel \n";
    cout << "Car 1 drove: " << miles << " miles \n";
    cout << "Car 1 gets: " << mpg1 << " miles per gallon \n" << endl;

    cout << "Car 2 used: " << liters << " liters of fuel \n";
    cout << "Car 2 drove: " << miles << " miles \n";
    cout << "Car 2 gets: " << mpg2 << " miles per gallon \n" << endl;
}
```

Here is where I expected the results of the inputs (5 30) and (55 123) to print out in their respective correct spots.

```
Car 1 used: 55 liters of fuel
Car 1 drove: 123 miles
Car 1 gets: 22.7119 miles per gallon

Car 2 used: 55 liters of fuel
Car 2 drove: 123 miles
Car 2 gets: 8.46533 miles per gallon

Car 1 has better fuel efficiency.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you simplify your code (i.e. get it to do less) the bugs will be obvious and you may not need our help at all.

Comment: Where is the wrong value coming from ? From which variable? How should the right value get into that variable? Or if it does get into it, is it possible that your code does overwrite it at some point? Your output function only gets one value for liters and one value for miles; it does however get two values for mpg. It prints liters twice, how do you expect that to produce two different valus?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for your input and guidance. I added `liters1, liters2, miles1, miles2` to my functions and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Car 1 and Car 2 have their own individual set of values for `liters` and `miles`, but you are only saving the last set entered by the user, and then passing that last set to `displayResult()`, so you end up displaying the same values for both Cars.  You need to pass both sets individually, just like you already are for both calculated MPGs, eg:

```
double mpg(double miles, double liters);
void userInstruction();
void displayResult(double miles1, double liters1, double mpg1,
                   double miles2, double liters2, double mpg2);

int main()
{
    double miles1, liters1, mpg1;
    double miles2, liters2, mpg2;
    char keepGoing;

    do
    {
        userInstruction();
        cin >> liters1;
        cin >> miles1;
        //calling function
        mpg1 = mpg(miles1, liters1);

        cout << endl << endl << "Do the same for Car 2. \n" << endl;
        cin >> liters2;
        cin >> miles2;

        mpg2 = mpg(miles2, liters2);

        displayResult(miles1, liters1, mpg1, miles2, liters2, mpg2);

        //Allows for repeating
        cout << "Do you wish to keep going? (y/n)  \n";
        cin >> keepGoing;
    }
    while (keepGoing == 'y' || keepGoing == 'Y');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

static const double LPG = 0.264179;
double mpg(double miles, double liters)
{
    return miles / (liters * LPG);
}

void userInstruction()
{
    cout << "Please enter the liters of gasoline consumed as well as the miles travelled for Car 1. \n" << endl;
}

void displayResult(double miles1, double liters1, double mpg1,
                   double miles2, double liters2, double mpg2)
{
    cout << "Car 1 used: " << liters1 << " liters of fuel \n";
    cout << "Car 1 drove: " << miles1 << " miles \n";
    cout << "Car 1 gets: " << mpg1 << " miles per gallon \n" << endl;

    cout << "Car 2 used: " << liters2 << " liters of fuel \n";
    cout << "Car 2 drove: " << miles2 << " miles \n";
    cout << "Car 2 gets: " << mpg2 << " miles per gallon \n" << endl;

    if (mpg1 == mpg2)
    {
        cout << "Both cars have the same fuel efficiency. \n" << endl;
    }
    else if (mpg1 > mpg2)
    {
        cout << "Car 1 has better fuel efficiency. \n" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Car 2 has better fuel efficency. \n" << endl;
    }
}
```

That being said, consider using a `struct` or `class` to help you better organize the values and functionality of each Car, eg:

```
struct travelInfo
{
    double miles, liters;

    double mpg() const;
    void getUserInput(const string &prompt);
    void displayResult(const string &name) const;
};

void userInstruction(travelInfo &car1, travelInfo &car2);
void displayResult(const travelInfo &car1, const travelInfo &car2);

int main()
{
    travelInfo car1, car2;
    char keepGoing;

    do
    {
        userInstruction(car1, car2);
        displayResult(car1, car2);

        //Allows for repeating
        cout << "Do you wish to keep going? (y/n)  \n";
        cin >> keepGoing;
    }
    while (keepGoing == 'y' || keepGoing == 'Y');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

static const double LPG = 0.264179;
double travelInfo::mpg() const
{
    return miles / (liters * LPG);
}

void travelInfo::getUserInput(const string &prompt)
{
    cout << prompt << " \n" << endl;
    cin >> liters;
    cin >> miles;
}

void travelInfo::displayResult(const string &name) const
{
    cout << name << " used: " << liters << " liters of fuel \n";
    cout << name << " drove: " << miles << " miles \n";
    cout << name << " gets: " << mpg() << " miles per gallon \n";
}

void userInstruction(travelInfo &car1, travelInfo &car2)
{
    car1.getUserInput("Please enter the liters of gasoline consumed as well as the miles travelled for Car 1.");
    cout << endl << endl;
    car2.getUserInput("Do the same for Car 2.");
}

void displayResult(const travelInfo &car1, const travelInfo &car2)
{
    double mpg1 = car1.mpg(), mpg2 = car2.mpg();

    car1.displayResult("Car 1");
    cout << endl;

    car2.displayResult("Car 2");
    cout << endl;

    if (mpg1 == mpg2)
    {
        cout << "Both cars have the same fuel efficiency. \n" << endl;
    }
    else if (mpg1 > mpg2)
    {
        cout << "Car 1 has better fuel efficiency. \n" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Car 2 has better fuel efficency. \n" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is essentially how I fixed it and it worked but I wasn't sure why exactly, so thank you for the explanation. Also, thank you for the `struct` advice. It's not something we have covered yet, but it looks much cleaner that way so I will do some reading ahead on it.